# LNK1181 cannot open input file - Qt5, but worked when compiled from batch

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

The specific error is:

```
LNK1181: cannot open input file 'sqlite3.lib'
```

Everything was compiling and linking fine when compiling using batch with the MSVC comandline:

```
cl /MTd /EHsc /I "C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\include" /Ox ^
 C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\lib\Qt5Core.lib C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\lib\Qt5Gui.lib Lib\teVirtualMIDI32.lib Lib\sqlite3.lib ^
 Source\main.cpp Source\BasePort.cpp Source\PortContainer.cpp Source\BaseSql.cpp
```

But now I have to use MOC for the UI connections, so I've moved over to Qt Creator.

Heres the .pro thing:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-12-23T15:49:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MidiMod
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    BasePort.cpp \
    BaseSql.cpp \
    PortContainer.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    BasePort.hpp \
    BaseSql.hpp \
    PortContainer.hpp \
    SetupUi.hpp \
    sqlite3.h \
    teVirtualMIDI.h

FORMS    += \
    errormsg.ui \
    main.ui

LIBS += \
    teVirtualMIDI32.lib \
    sqlite3.lib

DISTFILES += \
    sqlite3.dll \
```

**Edit:**

Now I'm also getting `LNK1181: cannot open input file 'teVirtualMIDI32.lib'`

Comment: This may be a naive question, but are all these files available in the same directory (or however it is linked)? The command line provided an explicit directory of the library: `Lib\sqlite3.lib`.

Comment: @hauron when I was compiling from command line I had a different directory layout with levels, but now the Qt project directory is just flat, all files are on the same level

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated, I apologize, but how about you stick to Visual Studio and use the Qt addon instead? It's easy to use. For the problem - as a test - I'd suggest using full paths, see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @hauron Full paths fixed everything _facepalm_.... but now im getting a weirder problem... there is discrepancy between opening the .exe and running it in Qt... wtf is happening

Comment: Try using -L and -l options in the LIBS += section. It should be -L/path/to/libs -llibname

Comment: @Lukeme9X: Probably due to missing .dll files in the directory .exe is built into. QtCreator knows where to find these, so it probably adds them to path prior to running. Either copy the right dlls into the working directory, or change the system PATH variable yourself.